# Conditional select from a table using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch

Im trying to make a select which only shows some information (a conditional select).

I mean, this is my table "usuarios":

> "usuarios" includes:**(id,username,name,lastname,password,type,status,date)**

Take a look:

[image]

My goal is to make a select that only shows the users with **"type" = 1  AND "status" = 1**

Take a look:

[image]

I have a done a select but it shows every usernames, it does not validates anything :/.

My program shows this, and it is not correct because it does not validate anything :/

[image]

Here is my code:

My controller file:

```
    public function edit($ID){

  $data['usuarios'] = $this->Crudmodel->get_usuarios();
  $data['record']=$this->Crudmodel->get_id_row($ID);
  $this->load->view('edit',$data);

}
```

My model file:

```
          public function get_usuarios() {
         $this->db->select('c.*')
             ->from('usuarios c');

       $q = $this->db->get();

          return $q->result();
}
```

My "edit"  file:

```
    <h2 align="center">UPDATE</h2>
<form method="post" action='<?php echo site_url('Home/saveupdate'); ?>'>
<tr>

    <td><input type="text" hidden name="txtid" value="<?php echo $record->id ?>"/></td>

</tr>
<tr>

    <td>
        <select name="txtcarr">
            <?php foreach($usuarios as $item):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $item->id;?>"><?php echo $item->username;?></option>
             <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>

    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>

</tr>
```

Dont know whatto do :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not only select the rows you want? Will it work as you expect if you put this in your model?

```
public function get_usuarios() {
   $this->db->select('id, username')
        ->from('usuarios')
        ->where(array('status'=>1, 'type'=>1));

   $q = $this->db->get();
   return $q->result();
}
```